# Powershell script to make pdf's from excel sheets

Tags: excel, powershell

Im trying to make a script which makes excel sheets into PDF's, and save using a name it gets from one of the value in the sheet. So far i got this:

[PS-script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQqtk.png)

Im getting a error and it doesnt save using the specifik name. Im able to print the value though and the PDF are created, so somethings working.

Error:

```
Join-Path : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ChildPath'. Specified
method is not supported.
At line:26 char:51
+  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $savepath -ChildPath ($value + ".pdf")
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

Bonus question: If i want it to move the excel after, what would i need to add, and where, as i plan on making this run daily and convert all the new files only.

Code:

````
#UPDATE DATA IN EXCEL FILES
#THEN CREATE PDF FILE
[string]$path = "C:\Users\PCUser\Desktop\JCI Praktik\PDF"  #Path to Excel spreadsheets to save to PDF
[string]$savepath = "C:\Users\PCUser\Desktop\JCI Praktik\PDF"
[string]$dToday = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type] 
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse 
 
# Create the Excel application object
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$objExcel.visible = $false   #Do not open individual windows
 
foreach($wb in $excelFiles) 
{ 
# Path to new PDF with date 


 # Open workbook - 3 refreshes links
 $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3)
 $worksheet = $objExcel.worksheets.item(1) #SK
 
 $value = $objExcel.Cells.Item(1, 6)
 $value.Text #this should give you back the Value in that Cell
 $workbook.RefreshAll()
 $filepath = Join-Path -Path $savepath -ChildPath ($value + "_" + $dtoday + ".pdf") 

 # Give delay to save
 Start-Sleep -s 5
 
 # Save Workbook
 $workbook.Saved = $true 
"saving $filepath" 
 #Export as PDF
 $worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath) #SK
 $objExcel.Workbooks.close() 
} 
$objExcel.Quit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
$value = $objExcel.Cells.Item(1, 6).Text  # You can also use '.Value' or '.Value2'
```

This could however easily result in a string having invalid filename characters, so to remove these use

```
$value = $value -replace ("[{0}]" -f [regex]::Escape([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))
```

Next, join into a complete filepath

```
$filepath = Join-Path -Path $savepath -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}.pdf' -f $value, $dtoday)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$value` variable needs to be a string,

You are using these two lines in your script,

```
$value = $objExcel.Cells.Item(1, 6)
$value.Text #this should give you back the Value in that Cell
```

so in the filepath variable

`$filepath = Join-Path -Path $savepath -ChildPath ($value + ".pdf")`

what is the output of `$value.text`? this would be a string, which should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. Im not getting an error now, but its not getting the value from the cell either, only a system.__ComObject (Tryed printing the &value). My excel is just a test atm with 10*10 cells with 1-100 numbers. Very new to PS, but know c++ and other languages.

Comment: My bad... added .text at the wring one. Working like a charm now, thanks a bunch